# Advanced query syntax: canonical name for 'Protected' file property

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-search

I'm trying to form a canonical query to search for all music files that aren't protected on a Windows 8 device. The reason for the canonical syntax is that the traditional 'kind:=music AND protected:=no' would need to be localized, which I want to avoid.

I have this:

```
System.Kind:System.Kind#Music AND System.Music.Protected:System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True
```

The first part, `System.Kind:System.Kind#Music` returns all music files properly. It's the second condition that I'm having trouble with. Does anybody know the canonical name for the 'Protected' property? It's available when you right-click/Details (under "Content") a music file.

I have been using this resource as a guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266512(v=vs.85).aspx#win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, the property is `System.DRM.IsProtected` and can be used like this:

```
System.DRM.IsProtected:System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#False
```